Updating Token Info on EtherScan
I need your help with updating my token info on EtherScan. I successfully deployed my token and verified my contract on EtherScan. The token does not have a logo and I wanted to add a logo and also update other information on EtherScan. I filled out the form several times but it was rejected. The EtherScan team does not provide a specific reason and keeps sending a general response that the submission does not meet the requirements. My token has a website, Twitter, and Telegram account with sufficient description. It is also available for trade on PancakeSwap, UniSwap, and Jupiter. I am really confused and do not know what is wrong with my submissions. Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

It's a forum for developers and technical questions here, i would recommend you to see that with the services and teams themselves.
